# How to to know if two SET datatype columns overlap in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I work with MySQL 8.x.
In my datatable, I have a table with a column named "days", whose datatype is set to "SET".
This column can take multiple values like: `'MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY','SUNDAY','HOLYDAYS'`

When a new entry is inserted in the table, I want to prevent saving if another entry in the table already has a column days containing one of the values of the new SET.

For example, inserting `'TUESDAY','SATURDAY','SUNDAY'` should blocks if an entry exists with values `'MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY'`, because `'TUESDAY'` is in each entry.

Here is my code (inside a SQL trigger on before insert):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.days <SOME OPERATOR HERE> NEW.days
THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' set MESSAGE_TEXT='Error !';
END IF;
```

Is there a specific operator or a simple way to solve my problem?

Comment: If SET definitions of two values are completely the same then you may check for overlapping with simple `(table1.column AND table2.column > 0)`

Comment: `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE (table.days AND NEW.days) > 0` ?

Comment: `>0` is excess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Akina. If I understand correctly, the AND operator allows to check overlapping on two column with SET datatype ? It doesn't seem to work. Am I not supposed to use some bit tricks with LPAD(BIN(... ?

Comment: SET datatype is really bit-mapped numeric, string values are stored in the table definition only, and they're attached during the string-context operations (insert/select, string compare and so on). So when you apply AND to the values then the context is numeric and their numeric representations are used for this operation. When the overlapping exists then according bit is set in both values, the result is over zero, and it is treated as TRUE (this is why `>0` is excess). If there is no overlapping then result is zero which is treated as FALSE.

Comment: A big thank you, it's crystal clear !

Comment: Given that the context is numeric, should I use & operator (bitwise AND) instead of AND ? I tried with AND but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I have loose this moment.